# Tag appears more than once QuickFix

Tags: c#, quickfix

I am sending a message MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh to a client application, but I am getting "Tag appears more than once" in the toAdmin method. The raw message string I am getting is

```
8=FIX.4.2|9=111|35=3|34=222|49=CLIENT1|52=20120217-18:57:44.233|56
=FixServer|45=189|58=Tag appears more than once|371=37|372=W|10=234|
```

Does anybody have an idea?

```
  QuickFix42.MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh message =
       new QuickFix42.MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh(new Symbol("QF"));

  QuickFix42.MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh.NoMDEntries group =
          new QuickFix42.MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh.NoMDEntries();

        group.set(new MDEntryType('0'));
        group.set(new MDEntryPx(12.32));
        group.set(new MDEntrySize(100));
        group.set(new OrderID("ORDERID"));
        message.addGroup(group);

        group.set(new MDEntryType('1'));
        group.set(new MDEntryPx(12.32));
        group.set(new MDEntrySize(100));
        group.set(new OrderID("ORDERID"));
        message.addGroup(group);

        Session.sendToTarget(message, session);
```

Comment: Your question has some errors, I think.  You must be wrong when you say that this error is being thrown during toAdmin(), because MDSnapshot is not an admin message.  Did you mean toApp()?  But really, it can't be toApp() either, because QF doesn't validate outgoing messages.

Comment: I think your scenario is actually this:  *Server is constructing this MDSnapshot message and sending to Client.  Client attempts to parse, and throws during `fromApp()` (not `toAdmin` or `toApp`).*

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a repeating group issue.  Your client is treating Snapshot message as a flat no-groups message, and then rejecting it because of the repeated tags.  (Your message construction code appears correct.)

When a client does not recognize groups, then that usually means the DataDictionary is misconfigured.

Make sure the following is set in your configuration, and I suspect that this particular problem will go away:

```
UseDataDictionary=Y
DataDictionary=path/to/your/DD.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem lies in your data dictionary - your FIX42.xml file should have the correct definition for MarketDataSnapshotFullRefresh, with the component block defined for the MDEntries repeating group.Also make sure your config file has "UseDataDictionary=Y" and that the path to your custom FIX42.xml is defined.

It is also possible that the order of the fields defined in your .xml file is not the same as your counterparty's spec. Make sure they are in the same order as well.